# Get the class type name which contains a field value

Tags: c#

Suppose i have this type of situation:

```
public class Layer
{
    public int layerIndex = 0;
}

public class Utility
{
    public static string GetLayerClassName(int index)
    {
        // whatever it returns
    }
}

public class ItemOne
{
    public Layer layer;
}

public class ItemTwo
{
    public Layer layer;
}

public class Executor
{
    private ItemTwo m_itemTwo;

    public Executor()
    {
        string className = Utility.GetLayerClassName(m_itemTwo.layerIndex);
        // So basically in this situation i need the name "Item Two"
    }

}
```

So basically i need the name of the class which contains that field variable.Is there any way to get that string?

EDIT: I edited the post so it matches closely my situation and not being too confusing.

Comment: are you familiar with `Reflection` this is one way..

Comment: You want `GetFieldClassName` to return the name of `m_fieldClass` when all you're passing it is an int? As you've outlined it in your question, this is almost certainly not possible.

Comment: Yes i feared that it could not possible. Thanks.

Comment: @DJKRAZE This is absolutely not possible with reflection.

Comment: Do you want m_fieldClass.GetType().ToString()?  That will return FieldClass, though probably the full name.

Comment: @KC-NH But `GetFieldClassName` can't write that code, because it doesn't know what variable's field is being passed in as its parameter.

Comment: So what happens if someone calls `GetFieldClassName` without accessing the field of a class for the parameter?  What if someone does `InfoClass.GetFieldClassName(5)`?  What should it do then?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve.  What is the purpose of InfoClass?   Executor appears to be asking for the type of it's own variable.

Comment: Nice sarcasm out there.I never insisted that i have good English grammar.

Comment: This is a really bad design IMO. You can't find a solution other than creating a class to represent an integer?

Comment: Explain why you need this. Show how you will call this code and use the result.

Comment: The way i intended to use it was for small debugging message from which the class error comes.I can't post whole the code inside so i just wanted to know is it possible or not.